# Grouping list elements by position in Prolog

Tags: list, sorting, prolog, grouping, declarative

I have found a very nice Erlang-implementation for grouping list members by position.

```
everynth(List, N) ->
   [ lists:reverse(Y)
     || Y <- lists:foldl(
                     fun(X, [H|T]) -> T++[[X|H]] end,
                     lists:duplicate(N, []),
                     List)
   ].
```

This sorts the provided list (List) by their index position into 3 groups:

```
everynth([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 3).
```

gives

```
[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]].
```

I would like to do the same in Prolog, but I don't know how to do it. Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Is the length of the original list a multiple of the second argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Literal translation

We can implement this in Prolog in a way that quite closely corresponds to the Erlang version.

For example, using Ulrich Neumerkel's [**`library(lambda)`**](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl):

```
everynth(Ls, N, Groups) :-
        findall([], between(1,N,_), Groups0),
        foldl(\L^[G0|Gs0]^Gs^append(Gs0,[[L|G0]],Gs), Ls, Groups0, Groups1),
        maplist(reverse, Groups1, Groups).
```

Depending on your Prolog system, you may need to import one or two *libraries* to run this.

Among other similarities, this carries with it a quite unfortunate drawback. **Exercise**: Which? Hint: Imeanapartfromthename.

## Alternative version

To overcome said drawback, I also show an *alternative* solution.

### Building block

The key building block I shall use is `with_remainder_mod/5`, defined as:

```
with_remainder_mod(N, L, R-L, I0, I) :-
        R #= I0 mod N,
        I #= I0 + 1.
```

In essence, this equips each *element* with the **residue** of its *index* (mod `N`). For example:

```
?- foldl(with_remainder_mod(3), [a,b,c,d,e,f], Rs, 0, _).
Rs = [0-a, 1-b, 2-c, 0-d, 1-e, 2-f].
```

We are almost *done*, because we can now use the ISO standard predicate `keysort/2`, and then the widely available `group_pairs_by_key/2` or similar library predicate:

```
?- foldl(with_remainder_mod(3), [a,b,c,d,e,f], Rs0, 0, _),
   keysort(Rs0, Rs),
   group_pairs_by_key(Rs, Gs).
Rs0 = [0-a, 1-b, 2-c, 0-d, 1-e, 2-f],
Rs = [0-a, 0-d, 1-b, 1-e, 2-c, 2-f],
Gs = [0-[a, d], 1-[b, e], 2-[c, f]].
```

### Full solution

In total, a full solution could look like this:

```
with_remainder_mod(N, L, R-L, I0, I) :-
        R #= I0 mod N,
        I #= I0 + 1.

every_nth(Ls0, N, Groups) :-
        foldl(with_remainder_mod(N), Ls0, Rs0, 0, _),
        keysort(Rs0, Rs),
        group_pairs_by_key(Rs, KeyGroups),
        pairs_values(KeyGroups, Groups).
```

The time complexity is Θ(n·log n), where *n* is the length of the list.

Note that this solution uses:

- **declarative integer arithmetic** via CLP(FD) constraints, to make this usable in *all directions*.
- `foldl/5` which is a very useful [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) that already ships with several Prolog systems.

Again, depending on your Prolog system, you may need to import one or two *libraries* to use these facilities and other predicates like `pairs_values/2` or equivalent ones.

### Examples

Your example query and the answer:

```
?- every_nth([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3, Ls).
Ls = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]].
```

Much more general queries are of course also possible:

```
?- length(Es, _), every_nth(Es, 3, Ls).
Es = Ls, Ls = [] ;
Es = [X1],
Ls = [[X1]] ;
Es = [X1, X2],
Ls = [[X1], [X2]] ;
Es = [X1, X2, X3],
Ls = [[X1], [X2], [X3]] ;
Es = [X1, X2, X3, X4],
Ls = [[X1, X4], [X2], [X3]] ;
Es = [X1, X2, X3, X4, X5],
Ls = [[X1, X4], [X2, X5], [X3]] ;
etc.
```

Note that a version based on `findall/3` **cannot** do this, because `findall/3` creates fresh *copies* of variables.

Here is a **benchmark** that may be useful for you to decide between different solutions:

```
?- length(_, E),
   portray_clause(2^E),
   N #= 2^E, I #= N // 2,
   length(Ls, N),
   time(every_nth(Ls,I,_)),
   false.
2^0.
% 150 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (80% CPU, 4545455 Lips)
2^1.
% 34 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (78% CPU, 2428571 Lips)
2^2.
% 62 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (83% CPU, 4428571 Lips)
2^3.
% 118 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (86% CPU, 6555556 Lips)
2^4.
% 230 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (93% CPU, 8214286 Lips)
2^5.
% 454 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (94% CPU, 9659574 Lips)
2^6.
% 902 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (96% CPU, 10488372 Lips)
2^7.
% 1,798 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (92% CPU, 9364583 Lips)
2^8.
% 3,590 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (99% CPU, 10316092 Lips)
2^9.
% 7,174 inferences, 0.001 CPU in 0.001 seconds (99% CPU, 11297638 Lips)
2^10.
% 14,342 inferences, 0.001 CPU in 0.001 seconds (100% CPU, 10491587 Lips)
etc.
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `portray_clause(E)` is in the right spot? For me, I only get the integer, not the `2^E` portrayed.

Answer (score 0):

Not really elegant but should work.

```
getEveryNth([], _, [], _).
getEveryNth([H|Ti], N, [H|To], N) :-
  getEveryNth(Ti, 1, To, N).
getEveryNth([_|Ti], M, Lo, N) :-
  M < N,
  Mp1 is M+1,
  getEveryNth(Ti, Mp1, Lo, N).

everyNthH(_, 0, [], _).
everyNthH([H|Ti], M, [[H|To] | Lo], N) :-
  M > 0,
  Mm1 is M-1,
  getEveryNth(Ti, 1, To, N),
  everyNthH(Ti, Mm1, Lo, N).

everyNth(L, N, LL) :-
  everyNthH(L, N, LL, N).
```

From

```
everyNth([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 3, L)
```

I get (`L` is unified with)

```
[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do some try & test to find the proper relation between indexes, you can see from variables' names that everynth_starting/4 has been 'uninlined' to ease debugging.

```
everynth(L, P, Gs) :-
    findall(G, (
        between(1, P, S),
        everynth_starting(L, P, S, G)
    ), Gs).
everynth_starting(L, P, S, G) :-
    findall(E, (nth1(I, L, E), S mod P=:=I mod P), G).
```

nth1/3 acts as a generator for pairs index/element